# Как посмотреть загрузку cpu пот отдельному процесу , при помощи Python?

Tags: python, процесс, cpu

Как посмотреть загрузку cpu пот отдельному процесу , при помощи Python ?

Я пробывал использовал psutil.

```
import psutil

PROCNAME = "zoiper"
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
        a=proc.pid
        p = psutil.Process(a)
        print(p.status)
        print(p.cpu_percent())
        print(p.cpu_affinity())
```

ответ

```
<bound method Process.status of <psutil.Process(pid=8129, name='zoiper') at 140221375194168>>
0.0
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Хотя загрузка есть, а показывает 0.0 ,  может я делаю чё не так ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Документация `psutil.Process`](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#process-class) явно говорит:

> When interval is 0.0 or None compares process times to system CPU
>   times elapsed since last call, returning immediately. That means the
>   first time this is called it will return a meaningless 0.0 value which
>   you are supposed to ignore.

`interval=None` по умолчанию, поэтому первое возвращаемое значение следует игнорировать. Второй и последующие вызовы отражают значения с прошлого вызова (документация не рекомендует чаще чем раз в 0.1 секунд вызывать).

Альтернативно, можно `interval > 0` передать в `.cpu_percent()` метод, чтобы за указанный период получить значение.

Comment: Спасибо , то что нужно ., что то с просмотрел.